# Вопросы, связанные с функционалом браузера

Tags: javascript, html

Как отменить открытие справки по нажатию `F1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать preventDefault

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
 if(e.key === 'F1') {
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
 }
});
```

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц  пожалуйста )